# Flutter ListView with different widgets and list items

Tags: listview, widget, flutter, scrollable

I'm not sure if I'm missing something. I'm playing around with Flutter and I want to build a (simple) view with some text widgets, buttons and other widgets (see picture below). These widgets should be followed by a list of items. The whole view (except the app bar, of course) should be scrollable - not only the items.

That's why I put everything inside a ListView. But I'm not able to do something like this (while `items` is a map with String values):

```
...    
home: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('App bar'),
  ),
  body: new ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Text('Some Text'),
      new FlatButton(...),
      new Image.asset(...),
      items.map((item)=>new Padding(
        child: new Text(item.title),
      )).toList()
    ],
  ),
),
...
```

What is the right way to get the desired view?

Thanks in advance!

[image: ListView with different widget types and some list items]

Comment: You could achieve that using Slivers, take a look a this great post by one of the Flutter team : https://medium.com/flutter-io/slivers-demystified-6ff68ab0296f

Comment: another option is using a SingleChildScrollView , Column  and create List<Widget> and add your items programmatically  with the order you want, after you have a list, set into the children property of your Column

Comment: here is a good solution for listview with extra widgets: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58281604/1068975

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/mixed-list

Answer (score 7):

You could use `ListView.builder` since is more efficient, because the items are only created when they're scrolled onto the screen. And in the first position you could put the widgets that aren't from the list, like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App bar')),
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length + 1,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index == 0) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Some Text'),
              FlatButton(child: Text('A flat button'), onPressed: () {}),
              Image.asset("An image"),
            ],
          );
        }
        return Text('Item ${items[index].title}');
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use like this

```
 ListView(
     shrinkWrap: true,
     children: <Widget>[
          Text('hi'),//first widget
          Text('hi2'),//second widget
          Flex(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: 3,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                              return ...
```

**Or**
Just tweak the count and the index.

```
 ListView.builder(
      itemCount: get.length + 2, // add room for the two extra
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if(index == 0){
         return Text('Custom any widget');
        }
        if(index == 1){
         return Text('Custom any widget');
        }
        index -= 2; // decrement index so that it's now in the range [0..length]
        return Bubble(
            style: styleSomebody,
            child: Container(
              ... 
            ));
      }),
```

Comment: This logic did it , mine was for two dynamic list tho.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following code in the `body`.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView( //add to Scroll whole screen
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            new Text('Some Text'), //Element-1
            new FlatButton(...),   //Element-2
            new Image.asset(...),  //Element-3
            items.map((item)=>new Padding(child: new Text(item.title),)).toList(), //Element-4
            ListView.separated(    //Element-5
                shrinkWrap: true,  //this property is must when you put List/Grid View inside SingleChildScrollView
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //this property is must when you put List/Grid View inside SingleChildScrollView
                itemCount: listItems.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return ListTile(
                        title: Text(listItems[i].Title),
                        subtitle: Text(listItems[i].Description),
                    );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return Divider();
                },
            ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

Comment: when scrolling listview others area not not scrolling(text and image)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by slivers, for fixed part use SliverToBoxAdapter and for scrolling list use SliverList. both fixed and list parts in page can easily scroll!!!

```
return CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverToBoxAdapter(child: FixedHeader()),
    SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
            YourListitems()
         })
    )]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **for** loop

```
...    
home: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('App bar'),
  ),
  body: new ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Text('Some Text'),
      new FlatButton(...),
      new Image.asset(...),
      for (var i in items)
      Padding(
        child: new Text(i.title),
      ))
    ],
  ),
),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body: SingleChildScrollView( //add to Scroll whole screen
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            new Text('Some Text'), //Element-1
            new FlatButton(...),   //Element-2
            new Image.asset(...),  //Element-3
            items.map((item)=>new Padding(child: new Text(item.title),)).toList(), //Element-4
           Expanded(child:ListView.separated(    //Element-5
                shrinkWrap: true,  //this property is must when you put List/Grid View inside SingleChildScrollView
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //this property is must when you put List/Grid View inside SingleChildScrollView
                itemCount: listItems.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return ListTile(
                        title: Text(listItems[i].Title),
                        subtitle: Text(listItems[i].Description),
                    );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return Divider();
                },
            ),
),
        ],
    ),
),
```

Answer (score -2):

Children in ListView are list of itens, so, if you want to display a button or text, your widget tree is:

```
Scaffold
 appBar: AppBar
 body:  Container
   child: ListView       
            ListItem
            ListItem
            ListItem
```

Then, in your case, you can use a Column to display "fixed widget" (text, button) + listview scrollable:

```
Scaffold
 appBar: AppBar
 body:  Column 
     [
        Text,
        Buttom,
        ListView
          ListItem
          ListItem
          ListItem
     ]
```

Comment: I'm afraid putting a ListView under Text and Button inside of a column makes only the ListView scrollable. I want everything inside the column to be scrollable.

Comment: got it. for that case, slivers fit well. congrats