# flutter add widgets on top and bottom to a listview

Tags: flutter

Trying to add some widgets to before of a listview....
I searched and found to use expanded like:

```
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Test Listview'),
    ),
    body: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('header'),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: providerApp.domains.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container( ......
```

But the issue here is that the Text('header') will be fixed, looking for some way where the the widget scrolls together with listview...

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can achieve this by using listview inside list view, below is sample code please check

[image]

```
 body: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 40,
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Header',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ListView.builder(
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 50,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.lime,
            height: 60,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Child $index',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      Container(
        height: 40,
        color: Colors.deepOrange,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Footer',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you !!! I was also made it with slivers and SliverToBoxAdapter but I like your solutions better

Comment: Your welcome, also pls upvote the answer if it's good. The StackOverflow rating system doesn't count accepted answers in a specific tag rating. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: this is the best solution.

Comment: Any idea how to implement a scrollbar?

Comment: An important addition to the answer explanation: do not forget to put `shrinkWrap: true` in the list builder.

Answer (score 4):

```
body: Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: ListView(
     children: Widget[
       Container(
         width: MediaQuery.of(context).width,
         height: 50,
         alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center
         child: Text("HEADER")
      ),
      for(var i =0;i<providerApp.domains.length;i++)
      Container(
         width: MediaQuery.of(context).width,
         height: 50,
         alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center
         child: Text("Child $i")
      ),
      Container(
         width: MediaQuery.of(context).width,
         height: 50,
         alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center
         child: Text("Footer")
      )
    ]
  )
)
```

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width

and

MediaQuery.of(context).size.height

Answer (score 2):

Here's How to **Add static widget at end of listview builder**

- Create the ListBulder
- Create Condition in If(index == [yourWidgetList].length – 1)
- Then Return your Footer widget
- Else Return rest of the top Widgets

[Full Article on this](https://www.flutterdecode.com/how-to-add-static-widget-at-end-of-listview-builder-flutter-code-example/)

In the Example Code, I Created a List

```
List listTiles = ["A", "B", "C", "Footer"];
```

Now I Used this List with the list View Builder To populate this List

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: listTiles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index == listTiles.length - 1) {
          return Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(listTiles[index]),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(listTiles[index]),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
```

There are also Some Other Methods To achieve this
Check [Other Ways](https://www.flutterdecode.com/how-to-add-static-widget-at-end-of-listview-builder-flutter-code-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
body : Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child : ListView.builder(
         itemCount : providerApp.domains.length + 1,
         itemBuilder : (BuildContext context, int index){
             Widget result;
             if(index == 0){
               result = Text("Header");
             }else{
               result = Container(..Your list item code here.);
             }
             return result;
         },
      ),
    )
```

PS: If you want add widget to bottom of list, condition is `provider.domain.length + 1`.

I hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning `ListTile` not `Container` now and your tiles will be titled according to the `ListTile` `title:` property field where "providerapp.domains" is the list of strings.

```
Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
      Text('header'),
      ListView.builder(
        itemCount: providerApp.domains.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('${(providerApp.domains)[index]}'),
          );
        },
      ),
    ]),
)
```