# Flutter / Dart: How to add an extra widget at the bottom of a ListView?

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview

I need to add a Text Widget at the end of a listview.
I came up with this code snippet based on my need. This code was based on [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278622/flutter-add-widgets-on-top-and-bottom-to-a-listview) codes.

**The Issue with this code is, it is not scrollable.** How can I fix this? what is the best way to add a widget to the end of a ListView?

```
    List<Widget> listItems = [];
    int listItemCount = 0;
    listItems.addAll(snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
      if (data['status'] == true) {
        listItemCount++;
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(data['full_name']),
          subtitle: Text(data['company']),
        );
      } else {
        return SizedBox();
      }
    }).toList());

    return ListView(children: <Widget>[
      ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: listItems,
      ),
      (listItemCount > 0) ? Text('All Finish') : Text('Not available'),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ListView.separated

```
ListView.separated(
     itemCount: listItems.length,
     separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
       if(index == ListItems.length-1){
         return Container(height: 50, color: Colors.red);
       }
       else {
         return SizedBox();
       }
     },
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
```

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks. But only after changing the if line as `index==ListItems.length-2`. Still, trying to understand Why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a tile to the end of `listItems`? Something like this:

```
...
const finalTile = ListTile(
  title: Text((listItemCount > 0) ? Text('All Finish') : Text('Not available')),
);
listItems.add(finalTile)

return ListView(children: <Widget>[
  ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: listItems,
  ),
  ,
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried this already. I can't actually do that, because for every `listItemCount++;`, the widget tries to rebuild. This is not the actual code, this is similar in structure to the code I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple.. Check this code snippet

```
return ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: listItems.length + 1, // here is the trick, we are adding +1 for extra widget at bottom
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     if (index < listItems.size - 1)
          return new Text("List Item");
     else
        return new Text("Last Extra widget"); // This will be the extra widget at last
    }
  )
```